# GET not able to find URL

Tags: php

I have made a basic Laravel project and had configured my api.php file to have a GET route when I want to fetch data for my project, but whenever I try to load the data on browser or perform a GET on the link (localhost:8000/data) from postman, it shows Error 404 Not Found. It seems that the GET is not able to find the URL that I had mentioned above. How can I get this issue sorted?

Comment: Show us the code where you added this route; otherwise, we'll just be making wild guesses at what you might have done, which is a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this applies to you from the question. But Laravel prepends /api/ to API routes by default.

Maybe try requesting from localhost:8000/api/data?